# horizontal recyclerView with wrap_content in vertical recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app I have a situation in which I have to create horizontal RecyclerView in vertical RecyclerView. Their are some rows which will show casual details and in some it will show a horizontal RecyclerView.

I have set the height of horizontal RecyclerView to wrap_content which is not visible. But when I have added hardcoded height to it, then RecyclerView is visible. I have searched a lot regarding this problem but I didn't got any working or convincing solution.

Here is my adapter class

```
public class HomeRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRVAdapter.HomeViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> data;
private Context ctx;
private int selectedIndex;

public HomeRVAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> val) {
    data = val;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    selectedIndex = -1;
}

@Override
public HomeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctx).getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_home_recycler, null);

    return new HomeViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final HomeViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (getItemCount() == position+1) {
        holder.categoryLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.productLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(ctx);
        manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

        ArrayList<SubCategoryDetails> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
        list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
        list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
        list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
        list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
        list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
        list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
        list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
        list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
        list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
        list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
        list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());

        holder.subCatRV.setAdapter(new PromoProductAdapter(list, holder.subCatRV));
        holder.subCatRV.setLayoutManager(manager);

    } else {
        holder.categoryLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.productLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (selectedIndex == position) {
            holder.subCatGrid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            showGrid(holder);
        } else {
            holder.subCatGrid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.catTR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (selectedIndex == position) {
                    holder.subCatGrid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    selectedIndex = -1;
                } else {
                    selectedIndex = position;
                    showGrid(holder);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private void showGrid(HomeViewHolder holder) {
    ArrayList<SubCategoryDetails> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
    list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
    list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
    list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
    list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
    list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());
    list.add(new SubCategoryDetails());

    SubCategoryGridAdapter adapter = new SubCategoryGridAdapter(list);

    holder.subCatGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
    holder.subCatGrid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

class HomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RecyclerView subCatRV;
    TextView catTitleTV, productNameTV;
    ImageView productIV;
    NonScrollableGridView subCatGrid;
    LinearLayout categoryLL, productLL;
    TableRow catTR;

    public HomeViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        subCatRV = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.subCatRV);
        productNameTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productNameTV);

        catTitleTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.catTitleTV);
        productIV = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.productIV);
        subCatGrid = (NonScrollableGridView) view.findViewById(R.id.subCatGrid);
        categoryLL = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.categoryLL);
        productLL = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.productLL);
        catTR = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.catTR);
    }
}

class SubCategoryGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<SubCategoryDetails> subCatData;

    public SubCategoryGridAdapter(ArrayList<SubCategoryDetails> subCatData){
        this.subCatData = subCatData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return subCatData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((Activity) ctx).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_sub_cat_grid, null, true);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}

class PromoProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PromoProductAdapter.PromoHolder> {
    ArrayList<SubCategoryDetails> data;
    RecyclerView horizontalRV;

    public PromoProductAdapter(ArrayList<SubCategoryDetails> data, RecyclerView horizontalRV){
        this.data = data;
        this.horizontalRV = horizontalRV;
    }

    @Override
    public PromoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctx).getLayoutInflater();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_promoted_product, null);

        if (horizontalRV != null) {
            int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
            horizontalRV.getLayoutParams().height = height;
        }

        return new PromoHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PromoHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    class PromoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public PromoHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please help me to get this problem solved.

Comment: Can you post the adapter code?

Comment: Typically RecyclerView will not `wrap_content` height.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @mr.icetea what do you suggest to manage height of my RecyclerView

Comment: @KislayKumar it looks look like hack, but did you try wrap your RecyclerView in some layout and set height if this layout and leave RecyclerView with match_parent attribute?

Comment: @Dima Its not working I have tried that too....
Any other way rather than adding hardcoded height?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution can be to keep the height hardcoded (as it is a horizontal view, height can stay fixed) and then hide the horizontal recycler view if the input is empty.

```
if(list.size() == 0){
   horizontalRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on my own. I have used a custom LinearLayoutManager that I have found from [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=74772&aid=747720007000&name=MyLinearLayoutManager.txt&token=ABZ6GAeGwZykLcmSj13gL_-OgAQ8l1aI4g%3A1443002493256).

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                      int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

    measureScrapChild(recycler, 0,
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            mMeasuredDimension);

    int width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
    int height = mMeasuredDimension[1];

    switch (widthMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            width = widthSize;
            break;
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            height = heightSize;
            break;
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                               int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
    View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
    if (view != null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
        int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
        view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
        measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth();
        measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        recycler.recycleView(view);
    }
}}
```

Just have to add this LinearLayoutManager to your RecyclerView that's it.

Thanks all
Cheers!!!

Comment: This might have worked at one time, but doesn't work anymore. Tried it and it crashed in trying to measure something that did not exist. But measuring only the first item doesn't seem appropriate anyway.